# Laravel cashier mollie

Tags: laravel, webhooks, mollie

We use laravel cashier mollie on our project.

Here’s a scenario that should be:

1. Trial week period for 1,99 euro
2. Monthly subscription for 6,99 euro

We create a subscription with the first payment. Payment goes successfully, subscription creates, we receive webhook but in the order_items table there are created 3 records:

1. First for this amount and without orderID
2. Second with null description but with orderID
3. Third description contains subscription dates, orderID and all the info.

After the third one we don’t receive a webhook from Mollie.

Has anybody met the similar issue?

Comment: You should reach out to Mollie Support or create an issue in their GitHub repository. This question doesn't really fit the Q&A format for Stack Overflow.